# PHP if statement error on echo

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
    $data = User::all(); //get all users
    $providercounter = $data->pluck('provider'); //just pay attention to their provider column

    if($providercounter == ""){
      echo 'site'.$providercounter->count();
    }ifelse($providercounter == "facebook"){
      echo 'facebook'.$providercounter->count();
}
dd($providercounter);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)
```

on this line:

```
echo 'facebook'.$providercounter->count();
```

#### What I try to do:

I want to get my provider column data, so I can use it in my chart. **With code above i try to make something like:**

1. provider = Null -> `echo site 20` `//20 is count of users which their provider column is null`
2. provider = facebook -> `echo facebook 10` `//10 is count of users which their provider column is facebook`

So I can get count of users of each provider. (facebook 10 users), (site 20 users) etc.

Where I'm wrong?

## UPDATE

Thanks for helps now I have results, but not as expected:

Here is my completed code

```
$data = User::all();
    $providercounter = $data->pluck('provider');
     if($providercounter == ""){
      echo 'site'.$providercounter->count();
    }elseif($providercounter == "facebook"){
      echo 'facebook'.$providercounter->count();
    }elseif($providercounter == "google"){
      echo 'google'.$providercounter->count();
    }elseif($providercounter == "linkedin"){
      echo 'linkedin'.$providercounter->count();
    }elseif($providercounter == "github"){
      echo 'github'.$providercounter->count();
    }
    dd($providercounter);
```

My result is:

```
Collection {#634 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => null
    1 => "google"
    2 => "facebook"
    3 => "facebook"
  ]
}
```

What I expected was something like:

```
site => 1
facebook => 2
```

so it has my echo such as `site, facebook, etc.` and count of their values like `1, 2, ....`

Any idea?

Comment: typo -> `ifelse`

Comment: Check if/else-conditions http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the below code

Your issue is with `ifelse`, it must be `elseif`

```
$data = User::all(); //get all users
$providercounter = $data->pluck('provider');

if ($providercounter == "") {
      echo 'site'.$providercounter->count();
} elseif ($providercounter == "facebook") {
      echo 'facebook'.$providercounter->count();
}
dd($providercounter);
```

Comment: thank you i updated my question

Answer (score 1):

try with else if

```
 if($providercounter == ""){
      echo 'site'.$providercounter->count();
    }elseif($providercounter == "facebook"){
      echo 'facebook'.$providercounter->count();
}
```

Comment: thank you i updated my question

Answer (score 1):

The error you are facing is due to not using **else** or **else if**.

Try using

```
$data = User::all(); //get all users
    $providercounter = $data->pluck('provider'); //just pay attention to their    provider column
    if($providercounter == ""){
      echo 'site'.$providercounter->count();
    }else if($providercounter == "facebook"){
      echo 'facebook'.$providercounter->count(); } dd($providercounter);
```

Comment: thank you i updated my question